# Convert a list with string lists into an list with integer lists

Tags: python

I'm loading this map file

```
3
15
8
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 7 3 4 4 5 8 3 4 5 9 0 0 0 2
0 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 13 0 0 0 12
0 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 13 0 0 0 12
```

using this

```
lines = [line.strip("\n").split(" ") for line in open("/Resources/Maps/level1.map")]
```

which spits out

```
['3']
['15']
['8']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '7', '3', '4', '4', '5', '8', '3', '4', '5', '9', '0', '0', '0', '2']
['0', '12', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '13', '0', '0', '0', '12']
['0', '12', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '13', '0', '0', '0', '12']
```

---

This current format is exactly as I want it
the first three lines tell me the number of maps, number of rows, number of columns
but not in the type that I want it.

The output is a list with lists of strings, how can I turn this into a list of lists with integers?

Would it be possible to do this directly within the line I used to load the map?

Comment: So cast the values to int in the list comprehension?

Comment: Try this: `lines = [list(map(int, line.strip("\n").split(" ")) for line in open("/Resources/Maps/level1.map")]`

Comment: I don't think I've seen `open` in a list comprehension before, I don't know what happens when you exit this list comp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `map` to convert all elements in a list to int.

**Ex:**

```
lines = [map(int, line.strip("\n").split(" ")) for line in open("/Resources/Maps/level1.map")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings) the result like:

```
lines = [[int(num) for num in line.split(" ")]
         for line in open("file1")][3:]
```

#### Result:

```
[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8, 3, 4, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2], 
    [0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 12],
    [0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 12]
]
```